# Как передать значение классу?

Tags: java

**Вот код:**

```
 public class Human{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person pers = new Person();
        pers.present();
    }
}

class Man{
    // String name;
    // int age;
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Hello, my is name, - " + name + ", am - " + age);
    }
}

class Woman{
    String name;
    int age;
    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Hello, my is name, - " + name + ", am - " + age);
    }
}

class Person{
    //Создаем муж. пол
    Man Oleg;
    Man Vadim;
    Man Pasha;
    //Создаем жен. пол
    Woman Masha;
    Woman Anna;
    Woman Lutic;
    public void present(){

        String olegName = "Олег";
        String vadimName = "Вадим";
        String pashaName = "Паша";

        Oleg = new Man();
        Vadim = new Man();
        Pasha = new Man();

        String mashaName = "Маша";
        String annaName = "Анна";
        String luticName = "Лютик";

        Masha = new Woman();
        Anna = new Woman();
        Lutic = new Woman();

        Oleg.talk();
        Vadim.talk();
        Pasha.talk();
    }
}
```

**Подскажите пожалуйста, мне нужно вывести следующий код:**

```
System.out.println("Hello, my is name, - Oleg);
```

Я классы создал, объекты тоже, но не знаю, как сделать, так, чтобы каждый объект говорил свое имя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Передать имя в конструкторе или создать сеттер.

```
class Man{
     String name;
     int age;

    public Man(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void talk() {
        System.out.println("Hello, my is name, - " + name + ", am - " + age);
    }
}
```

И при создании объекта, передать в него значения.

```
Man Oleg = new Man("Олег", 25);
Oleg.talk();
```

Comment: Спасибо Виталий! Слушай, как похоже на python.